# When installing Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials, should DHCP be turned off first on router?

Tags: dhcp

Or should it be left on for setup, then DHCP on router turned off after setup so server does DHCP.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess it depends on how long the setup process takes, whether or not you're doing it during production hours, and how much of their current DHCP lease is still available on your DHCP clients. Personally, I would turn it off on the router before beginning set up.

Comment: Yeah, it's just for my small office on off time and starting the server install over (new server).  Thank you Joe, much appreciated.  You always have great advice and proper answers I notice! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your router lets you change your DNS settings, you want to let the server handle DHCP. You want to set your server as DNS since this will let your clients resolve to Active Directory, but it doesn't really make a difference if the router or the server does it

Comment: Thank you.  Yeah, I tried testing removing power to the Internet router to see what would happen to the clients on the active directory network and they lost AD connectivity (couldn't authenticate).  So was told here that my server needs to be the dhcp not the router.  So this is where I am at.  Have other problems to fix, so redoing the server before I get too far along. I'll disable dhcp on router then reinstall ws2012r2e. Thank you.